# Javascript code folding only works for functions with Web Essentials

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, web-essentials

I've got Web Essentials 2.5.3 installed in Visual Studio 2013 and the code folding feature works fine for function declarations but fails to show expand/collapse icons for object literals and array literals.  Its driving me nuts and I can't seem to find anything in the Web Essentials settings to control these settings.

Has anyone encountered this issue or know of a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. But I have found a work around for this, follow these 2 steps
1.select code snippet you want fold.
2.right click on selection, go to outlining Hide Selection. Short cut: (Ctrl+M, Ctrl+H)

This will work for you.